# ARM bit field extract?

Tags: arm, bit-manipulation

Can someone explain what this instruction does and translate it to C?

```
ubfx.w          r3, r11, #0xE, #1
```

According to the ARM reference manual, it does a "*signed and unsigned bit field extract*" but I'm not good with all that bitwise stuff.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

UBFX just extracts a bitfield from the source register and puts it in the least significant bits of the destination register.

The general form is:

```
UBFX dest, src, lsb, width
```

which in C would be:

```
dest = (src >> lsb) & ((1 << width) - 1);
```

The C equivalent of the example you give would be:

```
r3 = (r11 >> 14) & 1;
```

i.e. r3 will be 1 if bit 14 of r11 is set, otherwise it will be 0.

See: http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0489c/Cjahjhee.html

Comment: A minimal runnable example of `ubfm` with assertions: https://github.com/cirosantilli/arm-assembly-cheat/blob/4a95d6a02514be6f6c22483752c24a2e14c1390b/v8/ubfm.S