# Extract bits from start to end in javascript

Tags: javascript

In Java script I want to extract bits 13 to 16 from integer number.
Example: If I extract bits 13 to 16 from number 16640 then output will be 2

I have searched on google and found few [links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011700/how-do-i-extract-specific-n-bits-of-a-32-bit-unsigned-integer-in-c) but they are in C language.

Comment: `parseInt( 16640 .toString(2).slice(-16, -13), 2 );`

Comment: Please show us what you've tried.

Comment: Javascript's bit operators are very similar to C's. Are you sure the solutions you found with Google don't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your bit count starts at 0:

```
var extracted, orig;

orig = parseInt("16640", 10); // best practice on using parseInt: specify number base to avoid spurious octal interpretation on leading zeroes (thx Ken Fyrstenberg)
extracted = ((orig & ((1 << 16) - 1) & ~(((1 << 13) - 1))) >>> 13);
```

Explanation:

- mask the lower 16 bits of the original number
- mask the complement of the lower 13 bits of the result (ie. bits 13-31)
- you currently have bits 13-16 of the orignal number in their original position. shift this bit pattern 13 bits to the right.

Note that this method only works reliably for numbers less than 2^31. The docs (MDN) are [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Expressions_and_Operators#Bitwise_operators)

Comment: Upvoted, but just remember to specify base for parseInt or you could end up with parsing octals if the number has a leading 0 etc. (`parseInt(str, 10);`)

Comment: @KenFyrstenberg Thank you, merged your hint into the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Javascript's bitwise operations work essentially the same way as they do in C:

```
var bits13to16 = (number >> 13) & 15;
```

This shifts the number 13 bits to the right (eliminating bits 0-12) and masks all but the last 4 remaining bits (which used to be bits 13-16).  15 = 2^4 - 1.

Answer (score 0):

All suggestions are working but the simplest I think is given by @dandavis.

parseInt( 16640 .toString(2).slice(-16, -13), 2 );