# Separating a 32 bit address into parts

Tags: c

In C,
If I have a 32 bit binary address, how could I take bits 6 - 10 (5 bit value) and assign them to a new variable?
For example, the address:
00000001001010011000100100100011

I want to take this section:

0000000100101001100010 **01001** 00011

And store it in a variable, x.

Comment: Look for bitwise opertions.

Comment: `(address >> 5) & 0x1f`. Look into shift and `&` operators.

Comment: Note that it's bits 5 to 9, not 6 to 10.  Bits are numbered from 0.

Comment: duplicates: [How to read/write arbitrary bits in C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11815894/995714), [How do I extract specific 'n' bits of a 32-bit unsigned integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8011700/995714), [How to get specific bit segments of an integer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29959338/995714)...

Comment: VTRO OP wants to isolate address bits, not just integer bits.

Answer (score 3):

> If I have a 32 bit binary address, how could I take bits 6 - 10 (5 bit value)

Addresses are not really something that have arithmetic values in particular bits - that is very implementation dependent.  Code can convert an address to an integer type and then proceed.

OP apparently wants other [@paddy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66220264/separating-a-32-bit-address-into-parts/66223347#comment117074556_66220264) bits: [9 to 5](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080319/).

```
#include <stdint.h>

void *ptr = ....;
uintptr_t i = (uintptr_t) ptr;

//           v------v         Ignore 5 least significant bits, move all bits right by 5. 
unsigned x = (i >> 5) & 0x1F;
//                      ^--^  Mask: Only retain 5 bits.
```