# Obtaining range of bits its from a given no

Tags: c++11, bit-manipulation, bitmask

I am using the following function to extract n bits from a number. I got this function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8011700/how-do-i-extract-specific-n-bits-of-a-32-bit-unsigned-integer-in-c). For convenience I am posting it here. I would like to obtain bits from 0 to 9 and then in another statement bits 10 to 15. I am passing in 1033. I get the correct value of bits 0 to 9 but incorrect value for 10 to 15. I should get a 1 instead i am getting 1024 any suggestions ?

```
 unsigned createMask(unsigned a, unsigned b)
    {
        unsigned r = 0;
        for (unsigned i = a; i <= b; i++)
            r |= 1 << i;

        return r;
    }
```

Now i have this

```
unsigned short langId = 1033 ;// 10000001001
unsigned primary =   createMask(0,9) & langId; //gives 9 correct
unsigned sec = createMask(10,15) & langId;     //gives 1024 incorrect should be 1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bits of `sec` that you've set are still in the 10-15 bit positions. You need to shift them back towards the start. Otherwise you have a single `1` set at position 10 and 2<sup>10</sup> is giving your answer of `1024`

`sec >> 10`

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/U28wFn3EvxG1ifRU)